# When can element property be used as CSS selector (or why querySelector does not find my checkbox)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out when element properties can be used for CSS selectors. For instance, in the following snippet the `value` property exists in the checkbox elemenet (`checkbox.value` evaluates to `'on'`), but can't be used by querySelector until I explicitly set it's value:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("INPUT[type='checkbox'][name='vehicle']");
var value= checkbox.value; // evaluates to: 'on'
try {
    // This try throws:
    document.querySelector("INPUT[type='checkbox'][name='vehicle'][value='" + value + "']").checked=true;
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message); // prints: 'Cannot set property 'checked' of null'
}

document.querySelector("INPUT[type='checkbox'][name='vehicle']").value=value;
// This try checks the checkbox:
document.querySelector("INPUT[type='checkbox'][name='vehicle'][value='" + value + "']").checked=true;
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle">I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle">I have a car<br>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to commenters, I think I got the difference between the DOM properties and markup attributes. Now, back to my original question - *I would like to know, for a given element, how to tell if a specific property of it is in the markup or not*.

My Goal: I'm writing an algorithm that visits all element in the page, and then I need to find a specific element by a given set of properties. I want to first look for the element by CSS, then keep filtering the result by DOM properties. How do I know for each property if it is usefull for `querySelector` or not?

Comment: Your element doesn't have a `value` attribute declared in the markup, so it will not match any `[value]` attribute selector until you explicitly set it a value, after which it will then adopt a `value` attribute.

Comment: Can you explain more? What's the `markup`? And what's the difference between the JavaScript `checkbox.value` and the CSS attribute selector? And how do I tell the two attribute types appart in runtime?

Comment: HTML == HyperText Markup Language

Comment: Are you asking how to determine this programmatically, or are you asking for a list of all possible properties and corresponding attributes? The latter may be a little difficult; the former is pretty simple as long as you know the attribute to test for, but I can see how that would get tedious.

Comment: I'm asking the former. Given a set of property names, I want to check: 1. does the current element has this JS property initialize, and what's its value? 2. Is this property also exists in the markup, and is legitimate for later `querySelector` use? This is for automation (and recording) purposes.

Comment: Regarding your update, exactly zero properties are useful for `querySelector`, however some properties automatically create and update attributes. There are a handful of these property/attribute mappings, which are dependent to some degree on the type of element and other things. I was surprised to see that a `checkbox` input does seem to map its `.value`, since a `text` input does not

Comment: So, how about the following approach: I will use `qeurySelector` only with the `tagName`, `id` and `class` attributes (which I assume are always HTML properties) in order to initially filter the elements, and then programatically iterate over other properties and compare each element's property to the corresponding value I recorder.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` only selects the element if it is in DOM.

When you do `var value= checkbox.value;`, it is just using the internally set value, which was *not* in the DOM when it was parse. Try adding the following line and things should work. It changes the DOM so, it will work.

```
checkbox.setAttribute("value", "on"); // it updates markup hence works
```

**Full code:**

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("INPUT[type='checkbox'][name='vehicle']");
var value= checkbox.value; // evaluates to: 'on'
checkbox.setAttribute("value", "on");
try {
    document.querySelector("INPUT[type='checkbox'][name='vehicle'][value='" + value + "']").checked=true;
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: How can I get the attribute value only if it is in the markup? Is that the difference between `hasAttribute()` to `hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: @AmitJoki: Using `.setAttribute()` doesn't change markup. It changes the DOM element to add the attribute. Don't confuse markup (text) with JS objects, which are generated after parsing the markup.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Using `.setAttribute()` isn't bad. I'm just saying that you're confusing the term "markup" with the DOM. The `querySelector` method doesn't care at all about markup. It only cares about which attributes are present on the DOM element

Comment: Ok guys, I think I get it. The DOM element is a JavaScript Object, and the markup is the element parsed from the actual HTML. But how do I tell if a certain property in the JS object exists in the markup or not?

Comment: @Elist `$('input[value]')` will return only inputs with attribute value set in HTML markup. And to get this attribute (not the parsed property): `$(selector).attr('value')`

Comment: @Elist adding on to A. Wolff's comment, you could check `.length` also.

Comment: @Elist Oh i'm sorry, I was thinking it was a jQuery question, then use querySelectorAll() and getAttribute() methods or whatever because anyway, this is CSS valid selector

Comment: @AmitJoki - what do you mean by checking `.length`?

Comment: @Elist It checks for length of the NodeList. If it is `0`, there are no elements. If more than `0` elements are present.

Comment: I'm not sure I made myself clear... Given an element, I want to tell it's DOM properties and markup attributes appart, so I can later find the same element using `querySelector`.

Comment: @Elist: Some attributes automatically change when the related property changes. As such, you can't always tell the difference between the current state and the original state. If you need the original state, then create a custom attribute that you never change, like `data-orig-value="foo"`. Custom attributes should always start with `data-`. Though it would seem unusual to change the value of a checkbox.